# Struts2 Hello World jsp example error

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, tomcat6

I am trying to run a Hello World Struts2 project in Tomcat 6.

I keep getting:

```
  root cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware

  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1374)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1233)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.getClassInstance(ObjectFactory.java:96)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:398)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:355)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:460)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:189)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
```

However I do have the required jars for struts2 in the WEB-INF/lib folder for the project.

Jars:

struts-core
   xwork
   ognl
   freemarker
   commons-fileupload
   commons-io
   commons-lang

Any ideas?

I followed an online Struts2 HelloWorld example:

HelloWorld.action class:

```
  package za.co.vine.tutorialspoint.struts2;

  public class HelloWorldAction{
  private String name;

  public String execute() throws Exception {
  return "success";
  }

  public String getName() {
  return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
  }
  }
```

HelloWorld.jsp:

```
  <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     Hello World, <s:property value="name"/>
  </body>
  </html>
```

index.jsp:

```
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
   pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
  <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <h1>Hello World From Struts2</h1>
      <form action="hello">
        <label for="name">Please enter your name</label><br/>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Say Hello"/>
     </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

struts.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
   <struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="helloworld" extends="struts-default">

     <action name="hello" 
        class="za.co.vine.tutorialspoint.struts2.HelloWorldAction" 
        method="execute">
        <result name="success">/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
     </action>
  </package>
  </struts>
```

web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: open your core jar and check whether this class : org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware exists in the jar or not , or download the jar from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-core/2.0.11.2/struts2-core-2.0.11.2.jar

Comment: Give full stack trace of the error.

Comment: Okay I fixed the above error, I now get this:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.addConfigurationProvider(Lcom/opensymphony/xwork2/config/ConfigurationProvider;)V

Comment: @lulu88 Do not mix-and-match jar versions; use the version appropriate to your S2 version. Without providing any version info for the jars, it's impossible to be more specific. Also, consider using Maven/etc. to handle this.

Comment: Thanks Dave I am downloading the full struts 2.3.8 pack from Apache at the moment. Unfortunately I cannot use Maven, as we do not use that at work.

Comment: You can always use maven to set up a spike project for a given technology.  It's a very low bar of entry and allows you to accurately determine exactly the dependencies for the project in it's least case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add the following Jars only in the WEB-INF/lib. Remove all related jars if you don't have need.

```
asm-3.3.jar
asm-commons-3.3.jar
asm-tree-3.3.jar
commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
commons-io-2.0.1.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
freemarker-2.3.19.jar
javaassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
ognl-3.0.5.jar
struts2-core-2.3.7.jar
xwork-core-2.3.7.jar
```

If you dont have these jars then download it.

Here  **org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher**  is now deprecated .So Edit your web.xml from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <display-name>Struts 2</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
     org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
  </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Struts2 Application</display-name>

  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I guess this could do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping us! we are beginners and guys like you are really helping us. I am learning Struts2 by my own and facing the same problem as OP

Answer (score 3):

It seems the version of xwork-core jar that you are using is not compatible with the versions of other jars.

Try using [xwork-2.1.2.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/com/opensymphony/xwork/2.1.2/xwork-2.1.2.jar). I have used it earlier successfully.

If it still does not work, be sure you use the same versions of each and every jar as in the sample application.

**EDIT**:

As per your code, try changing

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
  return "success";
}
```

to

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
  setName("Honey Bunny");
  return "success";
}
```

It seems that since you have not called the setter, Struts is searching for the property name in the session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I downloaded the full struts 2.3.8 package from Apache, but still don't work. I get a aused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.views.gxp.inject.InjectedObjectContainer
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1387)
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:152)at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.register(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:216)

struts-core 2.3.8.jar
xwork-core-2.3.8.jar

Comment: Edit the question to add the code from struts.xml, view.jsp, action class. Then we'll be able to tell.

Comment: Since you are trying to use the latest version of Struts, there might be dependency issues. Start afresh as try this app:
http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-hello-world-example-1.html

Comment: Followed that D-Zone example and in my tomcat logs i still get an error:

`code` java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware

Comment: Did you take this example with all the jars inside it: www.dzone.com/sites/all/files/Example1_1.zip
Also, how do you add the jars to the project. If you are using Eclipse, select all jars -> right click -> Add to build path..

Comment: Probably, you have to run the Dzone example on tomcat 5.5. If that still does not work, try arvin_codeHunk's example below

Comment: Yeah i did, i finally got it to work on tomcat 6! But I had to remove the lib folder from the project itself and put the jars i need in tomcat lib folder.

Comment: If you don't realize the proper location of jars, "select all jars -> right click -> Add to build path" always helps

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, the problem might be in the server or in your IDE tool so clean both of them under project clean and under server clean respectively.

If you face the same problem again download struts2 from this link

> [struts2](http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/struts/examples/)
>   Just you have to copy the struts-blank.war from that folder and with *`the new workspace`* run one program (that struts-blank.war contains test programs) definitely it will work.

Comment: Did that. I get this error in my tomcat logs:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware

Answer (score 0):

No classdeffound error usually comes when you haven't got that class in classpath or there are more than one versions of that class in classpath. Troubleshoot using these two options you are there. I encountered this when I was working on my [JSP examples](http://www.deepakgaikwad.net/index.php/2009/04/13/java-server-pages-jsp-tutorial.html) for code samples.