# Why is my simple Struts2 example not working?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, struts2, glassfish

I am using Glassfish 4.0 with Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 and have downloaded the latest struts2 libraries. I have added all the struts2 jars to the project, just to be sure. I have created a Dynamic Web Project. This is my **web.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.demian.javabrains.action</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my **struts.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.demian.javabrains.action.TutorialAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

This is my **TutorialAction.java**:

```
package org.demian.javabrains.action;

import java.util.Date;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TutorialAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Hello from execute!");
        Date d = new Date();
        long milliseconds = d.getTime();
        if (milliseconds % 2 == 0)
            return SUCCESS;
        else
            return ERROR;
    }
}
```

The other 2 pages I created are simple `.jsp` pages: `success.jsp` and `error.jsp`, both in the home directory. If I input this url: `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/success.jsp`, I get the success page so it means that Glassfish is working but if I input this url: `http://localhost:8080/Struts2Starter/getTutorial.action` I always get http error 404. I followed the instructions on this page: [struts2 documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/hello-world-using-struts-2.html). Can anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

### EDIT

I tried debugging the application with `struts2-config-browser-plugin` by inserting this link

```
<a href="<s:url action="index" namespace="config-browser" />">Launch the configuration browser</a>
```

into my `success.jsp` page like it says here:http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/debugging-struts.html . When I click on the link it gives another 404 error. I don't understand. It's like Struts2 isn't working at all. Here is the log when I start the server: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/glassfish_server_startup.txt

### EDIT1

I installed Tomcat 8.0.11 and here's the error message I get when I start the server: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/tomcat8_server_startup.txt

Comment: Do you get any exception? Try to remove `init-param` from web.xml file.

Comment: Turn on devMode and set logging to debug. Is the `execute()` method being called at all? You might also try adding `namespace="/"` to your package declaration.

Comment: I removed the `init-param`. I also thought that it was a problem of where to put the `struts.xml` file so I pasted it everywhere and it still doesn't work. @DaveNewton I don't think the method is being called at all. It doesn't find the class and spits out only a 404 message. This is a screenshot of the file structure now: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/2014-09-04%2014_34_25-Java%20EE%20-%20Struts2Starter_web_WEB-INF_web.xml%20-%20Eclipse.png

Comment: @Ariel You should include the directory tree as text formatted as code in the question. What precisely do you mean by "doesn't find the class"? The `struts.xml` file should be at the root of the classpath by default.

Comment: It is at the root of the classpath. I put it inside src folder.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get any exception? Maybe during server startup/app deploy.

Comment: @Ariel Make sure it's actually being deployed. Turn on devMode, set logging to DEBUG, check your startup logs.

Comment: I actually get some errors. Here is the log when I start the Glassfish server: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/glassfish_server_startup.txt

Comment: Did you try to deploy on Tomcat or other servlet container?

Comment: hopefully you might have already figured out...this link though has a similar issue -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278258/struts2-hello-world-jsp-example-error

Comment: Please include your errors in the question itself.

Comment: I did. I put them in the last section of the question.

Comment: Read the comments in http://stackoverflow.com/q/24573688/1700321.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to make it work! First thing I did was to remove all the jars I included and add only the ones I needed. Here are the jars that I included: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/2014-09-05%2022_36_58-Preferences%20%28Filtered%29.png

After this, I configured the libraries in the Properties -> Deployment Assembly of the project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27349592/2014-09-05%2022_37_29-Properties%20for%20Struts2Tutorial.png

My **web.xml** file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Struts2Tutorial</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My **struts.xml** file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="basicstruts2" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.demian.javabrains.action.TutorialAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I still don't know exactly what was the problem but I guess that it may be because of the dependencies in the struts2 libraries.

Comment: And I really think that next time I will be using Maven.